# Java8: How method collect with 2 BiConsumer could return a value as a final result?

Tags: java-8, consumer, collect

java8 provide below method:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

From javadoc, about BiConsumer: Represents an operation that accepts two input arguments and returns no result.

According to the code below:

```
String forward = s.toLowerCase().codePoints()
.filter(Character::isLetterOrDigit).collect(StringBuilder::new,
                 StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                 StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
```

The 2nd, and 3rd arguments for collect is as below:

1. A BiConsumer used to accumulate each element of the stream into the resulting data structure; this example uses the appendCodePoint method.
2. A BiConsumer representing a combiner.

From my understanding, there are 2 Consumers, which receive arguments, and return no result, I could not figure out how can a string to be return in this case?

I google the internet but could not find any explanation.

*I know the meaning of StringBuilder::appendCodePoint and StringBuilder::append. But they are passed into 2 Consumers, and Consumer should not return any value. I feel confuse at this code.*

Comment: It's like a typical  MapReduce,  source -> aggregate -> combine. The second is aggregate and the third is  combine(reduce), finally returns a String.

Comment: Maybe you could check the source code of `Collectors.join()`, It's a better example to explain the pattern.

Comment: @PatrickChen Thank you for your feedback, I will read the source code. I know the last step is combine, I just don't know how 3rd argument, which is "combine" receive an argument as Consumer, which should not return anything. Theoretically, how can we explain this?

Comment: 3rd is a Function, can't return null. In Java stream, all the `intermediate` op or `terminal` op all have to return something. My understanding is if you look into `collectors.join` you'll find there is a `finisher` inside, the 3rd function is the source for the `finisher`

Comment: @PatrickChen You mean, 3rd is a Function, in which, it (i.e Function) receive 1 parameter which is "BiConsumer<R,R> combiner". If it is True, then, the whole thing is like scope of javascript, in which, Producer is an interface (i.e argument) to one Function, and Consumer is an interface (i.e argument) to another Function, both share scoping variables within a common scope.

Comment: The 2rd consumer's output is 3rd combiner's input. Then the 3rd combiner's output is the finisher's input. Finally, you get your String result.